# PyParsing: Is this correct use of setParseAction()?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, pyparsing

I have strings like this:

```
"MSE 2110, 3030, 4102"
```

I would like to output:

```
[("MSE", 2110), ("MSE", 3030), ("MSE", 4102)]
```

This is my way of going about it, although I haven't quite gotten it yet:

```
def makeCourseList(str, location, tokens):
    print "before: %s" % tokens

    for index, course_number in enumerate(tokens[1:]):
        tokens[index + 1] = (tokens[0][0], course_number)

    print "after: %s" % tokens

course = Group(DEPT_CODE + COURSE_NUMBER) # .setResultsName("Course")

course_data = (course + ZeroOrMore(Suppress(',') + COURSE_NUMBER)).setParseAction(makeCourseList)
```

This outputs:

```
>>> course.parseString("CS 2110")
([(['CS', 2110], {})], {})
>>> course_data.parseString("CS 2110, 4301, 2123, 1110")
before: [['CS', 2110], 4301, 2123, 1110]
after: [['CS', 2110], ('CS', 4301), ('CS', 2123), ('CS', 1110)]
([(['CS', 2110], {}), ('CS', 4301), ('CS', 2123), ('CS', 1110)], {})
```

Is this the right way to do it, or am I totally off?

Also, the output of isn't quite correct - I want `course_data` to emit a list of `course` symbols that are in the same format as each other. Right now, the first course is different from the others. (It has a `{}`, whereas the others don't.)

Answer (score 16):

This solution memorizes the department when parsed, and emits a (dept,coursenum) tuple when a number is found.

```
from pyparsing import Suppress,Word,ZeroOrMore,alphas,nums,delimitedList

data = '''\
MSE 2110, 3030, 4102
CSE 1000, 2000, 3000
'''

def memorize(t):
    memorize.dept = t[0]

def token(t):
    return (memorize.dept,int(t[0]))

course = Suppress(Word(alphas).setParseAction(memorize))
number = Word(nums).setParseAction(token)
line = course + delimitedList(number)
lines = ZeroOrMore(line)

print lines.parseString(data)
```

Output:

```
[('MSE', 2110), ('MSE', 3030), ('MSE', 4102), ('CSE', 1000), ('CSE', 2000), ('CSE', 3000)]
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is this the right way to do it, or am
>   I totally off?

It's one way to do it, though of course there are others (e.g. use as parse actions two bound method -- so the instance the method belongs to can keep state -- one for the dept code and another for the course number).

The return value of the `parseString` call is harder to bend to your will (though I'm sure sufficiently dark magic will do it and I look forward to Paul McGuire explaining how;-), so why not go the bound-method route as in...:

```
from pyparsing import *

DEPT_CODE = Regex(r'[A-Z]{2,}').setResultsName("DeptCode")
COURSE_NUMBER = Regex(r'[0-9]{4}').setResultsName("CourseNumber")

class MyParse(object):
  def __init__(self):
      self.result = None

  def makeCourseList(self, str, location, tokens):
      print "before: %s" % tokens

      dept = tokens[0][0]
      newtokens = [(dept, tokens[0][1])]
      newtokens.extend((dept, tok) for tok in tokens[1:])

      print "after: %s" % newtokens
      self.result = newtokens

course = Group(DEPT_CODE + COURSE_NUMBER).setResultsName("Course")

inst = MyParse()
course_data = (course + ZeroOrMore(Suppress(',') + COURSE_NUMBER)
    ).setParseAction(inst.makeCourseList)
ignore = course_data.parseString("CS 2110, 4301, 2123, 1110")
print inst.result
```

this emits:

```
before: [['CS', '2110'], '4301', '2123', '1110']
after: [('CS', '2110'), ('CS', '4301'), ('CS', '2123'), ('CS', '1110')]
[('CS', '2110'), ('CS', '4301'), ('CS', '2123'), ('CS', '1110')]
```

which seems to be what you require, if I read your specs correctly.

Answer (score -1):

```
data = '''\
MSE 2110, 3030, 4102
CSE 1000, 2000, 3000'''

def get_courses(data):
    for row in data.splitlines():
        department, *numbers = row.replace(",", "").split()
        for number in numbers:
            yield department, number
```

This would give a generator for the course codes. A list can be made with `list()` if need be, or you can iterate over it directly.

Answer (score -2):

Sure, everybody loves `PyParsing`.  For easy stuff like this split is sooo much easier to grok:

```
data = '''\
MSE 2110, 3030, 4102
CSE 1000, 2000, 3000'''

all = []
for row in data.split('\n'):
        klass,num_l = row.split(' ',1)
        all.extend((klass,int(num)) for num in num_l.split(','))
```