# How would I increase a integer value inside this loop?

Tags: python, integer

Trying to increase an integer value

So basically I'm trying to increase "e" so everytime I input a new line it would go 0, 1 etc

My input would look like this

```
example1
example2
```

```
def no(paths: str):
    e = 0
    for path in paths.split(" "):
        print("            ItemListData(" + str(e) + ")=(ItemDefination=" + path + '")')
        e = e + 1

while True:
    paths = input()
    no(paths)
```

When I do this I get this:

```
ItemListData(0)=(ItemDefination=example1")
ItemListData(0)=(ItemDefination=example2")
```

What I want is this

```
ItemListData(0)=(ItemDefination=example1")
ItemListData(1)=(ItemDefination=example2")
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 When I try putting it outside ```no``` I get this error ```UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'e' where it is not associated with a value```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: What do you enter as input? If you enter `example1 example2` I think you should already get what you want.

Comment: `e` is a local variable. It is created and initialized with `0` every time you call this function. So that's not gonna work this way. You can have a global variable and inside the `no` function, use `global` keyword.

Comment: If the string has spaces, do you also want each word to have a different `e` value, or should they all have the same one?

Comment: Your example input suggest one word per input, but your function is splitting. Can the input have the form `"example1 example2"`? If so, wht's the expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain state in Python without classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866419/how-to-maintain-state-in-python-without-classes)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming you want to have the value e increase every time you execute the function, you can do this:

```
def no(paths: str, e: int):
    for path in paths.split(" "):
        print("            ItemListData(" + str(e) + ")=(ItemDefination=" + path + '")')

e = 0
while True:
    paths = input()
    no(paths, e)
    e += 1
```

The first two lines of output, with inputs as follows:

```
execute1 (enter)
execute2
```

```
execute1
    ItemListData(0)=(ItemDefination=execute1")
execute2
    ItemListData(1)=(ItemDefination=execute2")
```

Note that you have an infinite loop. To not have an infinite loop, you could change the loop condition to something like `while e < x` to make the loop contents execute `x` times.

Comment: If the loop should execute `x` times you should use `for e in range(x):`

Comment: What does the output look like if the following string is entered (in one line): example1 example2

Comment: @Barmar while True is good for an infinite loop

Comment: @DarkKnight The input seem to be constrained by the OP in their question to only one word, but it's true it wouldn't make sense to split it. I asked this in comments to the OP. Maybe they want each `path` to be considered at the same level as a separated input?

Comment: @DarkKnight I know. My comment was referring to the last line that says `while e < x:`

Comment: @Barmar I know that, but the person who posted this used a while loop. I just suggested a slight change to their format. If they had used a for loop I would have suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let me just preface this by saying that this is a very basic question and you should really learn some basic debugging skills.

## Code Tracing

To see what's wrong, we need to first understand the code, so let's trace it to see what's actually going on.

1. `"example1"` gets stored in `paths`
2. `paths` (`"example1"`) is passed into the `no()` function
3. `e` is set to 0
4. `paths` (`"example1"`) is split by spaces
5. there are no spaces in `"example1"` so split returns `["example1"]`
6. we iterate through the elements of `["example1"]`
7. there is only one element in `["example1"]` and that is `"example1"`
8. `ItemListData(0)=(ItemDefination=example1")` is printed
9. the loop ends because there is only one element in `paths`
10. we leave the `no()` function
11. `"example2"` gets stored in `paths`
12. `paths` (`"example2"`) is passed into the `no()` function
13. `e` is set to 0
14. `paths` (`"example2"`) is split by spaces
15. there are no spaces in `"example1"` so split returns `["example2"]`
16. we iterate through the elements of `["example2"]`
17. there is only one element in `["example2"]` and that is `"example2"`
18. `ItemListData(0)=(ItemDefination=example2")` is printed
19. the loop ends because there is only one element in `paths`

## Solution

It is important to note step 3 and step 13.
`e` is set to 0 each time you call `no()`
But we don't want that to happen, do we? We want to keep track of how many times you enter a path. If we look at our stack trace again, we'll see that the loop that handles where you enter the path is the `while` loop outside of the `no()` function.
So the solution would be to put `e = 0`, and `e = e + 1` around the `while` loop instead of the `for` loop.

```
def no(paths: str, e: int):
    for path in paths.split(" "):
        print("            ItemListData(" + str(e) + ")=(ItemDefination=" + path + '")')

e = 0
while True:
    paths = input()
    no(paths, e)
    e = e + 1
```

## Conventions

1. `no()` should be renamed to `number_paths()` because `no` is a word that means something else in English.
2. indexes should usually use the `i` variable instead of `e`.
3. ItemDefinition is misspelt.
4. unless there is a really good reason to, please don't manually print a bunch of spaces. use `"\t"` for tabbing instead. `print("\t\t ItemListData(" + str(i) + ")=(ItemDefinition=" + path + '")')`
5. use f-strings for formatted strings. `print(f'\t\t ItemListData({i})=(ItemDefinition="{path}")')`
6. use `i += 1` instead of `i = i + 1`

Conventionally fixed code:

```
def number_paths(paths: str, i: int):
    for path in paths.split(" "):
        print(f'\t\t ItemListData({i})=(ItemDefinition="{path}")')

i = 0
while True:
    paths = input()
    number_paths(paths, i)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function itself to modify it's internal state, you can declare it globally.

But because in your case, `e` makes sense only as an attribute of the function `no`... why not making it just that, an *attribute*?

```
def no(paths: str):
    for path in paths.split(" "):
        print("            ItemListData(" + str(no.e) + ")=(ItemDefination=" + path + '")')
        no.e += 1

no.e = 0

for example in ["example1", "example2"]:
    no(example)
```

In this case, `no.e` is also declared globally (and it could be accessed by other functions, e.g. `print(no.e)`).

Note that because `no` is declared (in it's own `def`), you don't get `UnboundLocalError`, even if `no.e` wasn't yet declared, but you'll get `AttributeError` if you forget to declare it before using it.

It [may be considered and abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338101/python-function-attributes-uses-and-abuses) of function attributes, but in my opinion it's justified here since it makes explicit that `e` only has meaning as part of `no`. But if you want a more explicit manipulation of global variables, you can also do

```
def no(paths: str):
    global E
    for path in paths.split(" "):
        print("            ItemListData(" + str(E) + ")=(ItemDefination=" + path + '")')
        E += 1

E = 0

while True:
    paths = input()
    no(paths)
```

---

As a side note, `no` doens't seem to make sense outside a `for`/`while` loop since it's assuming the value `e` needs to be updated. And your `while` loop is doing little more than calling `no`. Is it really necessary to dissociate these two?

You could just do

```
e = 0
while True:
    paths = input()
    for path in paths.split(" "):
        print("            ItemListData(" + str(e) + ")=(ItemDefination=" + path + '")')
        e = e + 1
```

(Or put all that inside a function)